# Ansible 2.0 backslash issue

Tags: ansible

I'm having issues with backslash in Ansible 2.0

```
  mysql_user: name=someName
          password=somePassword
          priv=db.*:DELETE,INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE,LOCK\\ TABLES
          state=present
```

The error is:

```
"msg": "invalid privileges string: Invalid privileges specified: frozenset(['LOCK\\\\\\\\ TABLES'])"}
```

I tried a single backslash `priv=db.*:DELETE,INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE,LOCK\ TABLES` but no joy.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use spaces in unquoted strings with `param=value` syntax in Ansible.

```
mysql_user: name=someName
            password=somePassword
            priv="db.*:DELETE,INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE,LOCK TABLES"
            state=present
```

Advice: use dict-like parameters passing for complex arguments.